# Using PDO, is there a simpler way to get a single table var given an id?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Seems the cool kids are using PDO now.  Is my code below really the most streamlined to return a single var from an id?

Assuming 2 columns: 'id' and 'txt' - I just want to get 1 'txt' var for a specified id:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host;dbname;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
$st = $db -> prepare( "SELECT txt FROM wah WHERE id = :id" );
$st -> bindParam(':id', $id);
$st -> execute();
$result = $st -> fetch();
$txt = $result["txt"]; //finally!
```

Seems like a lot of code for the simplest case, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if connect counts, you need at least one additional line. Yet you can save later.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host;dbname;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$st = $db -> prepare( "SELECT txt FROM wah WHERE id = ?" );
$st -> execute([$id]);
$txt = $st -> fetchColumn();
```

But real PDO's power is `fetchAll()`
I wrote a tutorial for the cool kids, it worth a glance, http://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: ooh, interesting shortcuts here - the last line is really what I was looking for - getting the return value in 1 line instead of 2.  Testing it out now...

Comment: Read your tutorial. Nicely done. I've been doing alot of PDO stuff for a while but hadn't come to Jesus on the fetchAll constants.